# How can I read from secondaries using Java MongoDB Driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to force my MongoClient to read from secondaries, what I did was just:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(this.hostServerAddresses);
mongoClient.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondary());
```

but for some reason when I check mongostat only the primary is being used. Is there something missing?

I'm using the mongo java drive 3.1.0 and my mongo is 2.6.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your mongostat data.

Comment: @notionquest mongostat only shows me that my primary is receiving all requests, including the queries.